# edge microsoft edge (desktop) not loading google fonts

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, google-font-api

Edge on  Desktop is not loading google fonts. In fact, it's not even using "sans-serif" which is defined as fallback.

This behavior does not replicate in Mobile Edge.

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Febuz.png)

[How it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYafR.png)

Page url: www.puttout.golf

Comment: Show the code where you included the font

Comment: Do you happen to have a font by the same name installed on your machine from a remote service?

Answer (score 1):

I recently suffered this issue, and as @Sampson suggested, the cause was the SkyFonts service - Edge did not render fonts that it had loaded. Local copies of other Google typefaces, installed manually, were not affected.